# Scheduler hacking in Freebsd 5.2.1

Tags: kernel, freebsd, scheduler

How can I modify the thread priorities within, umm... the Timesharing class?
In case I want to implement my own scheduler, how would I have to do that? (like assigning priorites on my own terms)
How do I play around with the time slice values (or time quantums, as they are referred to by a lot of people)

*Edited* I figured that the time quantum variable is defined in sched_4bsd.c. But modifyig this variable, would modify the entire system's time quantum, won't it? If so, then how do I do it just for the TIMESHARE class?

Answer (score 1):

On current FreeBSD versions you can use `sysctl(8)` to change that, using the variable `kern.sched.slice`. To see if that exists in your version, type

```
sysctl kern.sched.slice
```

which should return something like:

```
kern.sched.slice: 12
```

If you get

```
sysctl: unknown oid 'kern.sched.slice'
```

then that sysctl doesn't exist yet on FreeBSD 5.2.1.